# Gradle sync error in Android studio when importing project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run this [open source project from github](https://github.com/ruinnel/nfctasker). I am getting this error in gradle. I am running Android studio in "Administrator mode". When i click on "try again" it starts downloading gradle-2.2.1-all.zip so went to [this site](https://services.gradle.org/distributions) and did download gradle-2.2.1-all.zip and have extract it to

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\

error in Android studio.

```
Gradle 'nfctasker-master' project refresh failed
Error:No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found.
```

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.ruinnel.nfc.tasker"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}
```

this is the error from log

```
2015-04-11 15:12:47,496 [2705228]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:322)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

I am new to Android studio
I am not able to understand what error means nor i am able to find anything on internet. Pleas help me. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Please post your build.gradle(project level).

Comment: @Shvet I have added it.I am new to Android studio so let me know if it not project level one

Comment: if you will check there are 2 gradle file one is for whole project and one is for module and it is written in `build.gradle(here)`.

Comment: i see. So one i posted was correct right?

Comment: yes. there is no problem in your gradle file. it is correct. error is from server to download it. your firewall may be trying to block it.

Comment: I dont have any firewall and anti-virus is disabled as well. Also i am running in administrator mode just to be on safe side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74996/discussion-between-shvet-and-user3933143).

Comment: I just have the same problem, please update if you find a solution :)

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576097/gradle-sync-error-in-android-studio-when-importing-project (removing the .gradle folder)

Comment: @George delete .grade from the project?

Comment: I deleted the main one, the one that was installed in my home directory. (well, deleted = copied it to another directory)

Comment: I am using Emanuel Fonseca's method and it is working currently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't build Android App with Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576871/cant-build-android-app-with-gradle)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As a temporary workaround you may download Gradle over `http` instead of `https`.

Edit `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, 
that should be available at the root of your project, and change distributionUrl to:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Comment: I am using your method and AS is downloading gradle so waiting for it to finished downloading. Will post the status after that.

Comment: This is working for me. I guess when the certificate has been fixed, I'll update it back to https

Comment: This method is perfect. It worked. The official link to gradles doesnt have https, instead it is http still Android Studio uses https

Comment: As a reminder, this might be a good thing to add to a  `git stash` operation so you don't always leave it this way. Awesome catch for what was busted.

Answer (score 11):

I think the site, https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ has wrongly configured ssl certificate issue. The certificate used for that domain is not a proper one for the domain name.
[image: Not trusted certificate]

I think you should wait until Gradleware fixes it, and in the meantime, you can temporarily use Emanuel's workaround.

Comment: By the way, I had asked Gradleware about this issue before putting my answer here as I'm having the same one. I hope they'll fix it soon.

Comment: hope they fix it soon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3933143 FYI, I think the certificate issue has been fixed. I no longer have this problem. I guess you should be fine now too.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem.

Please change your DNS server setting and reconnect to the Internet. Afterwards, try Gradle sync again.

## Google Public DNS

For example, you can make use of the [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/), which is *8.8.8.8* and *8.8.4.4*.

## OpenDNS

[OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/opendns-ip-addresses/) is an alternative.

Comment: I did change it google dns and flush dns using ipconfig/flushdns but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in gradle setting so that your service can be update
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip