# Can't build Android App with Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to build my Android App using the Gradle command line interface. I'v also add **GRADLE_HOME/bin** to the environment. Firstly, i used gradle init to generate the wrapper, gradlew in my project folder. Now, when i use this wrapper to build my app(**./gradlew build**) or use any of its functionality, it tries to download a gradle-2.3.zip file and fails at it(error message below). What I don't understand is why gradle try to download gradle again. Also, when I open the download url in my browser, it says that the page is insecure, which might be the cause of the error. What am I doing wrong? Is there a workaround? I have managed to download the zip file using my browser, but I don't know what to do with it. Here is the exception I got.

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS
>   name matching services.gradle.org found.  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1439)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:878)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:814)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)

Comment: Here is same problem...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576097/gradle-sync-error-in-android-studio-when-importing-project?noredirect=1#comment47301067_29576097

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem with the SSL certificate configuration on services.gradle.org right now

http://discuss.gradle.org/t/urgent-ssl-apache-configuration-for-services-gradle-org-is-bad/8808

The devs are aware and working on a fix.

This answer to the same question provides a workaround which may be suitable:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29576568/4776802

Answer (score 10):

Just update gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

update this:

-from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip
```

-to:

```
distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip
```

Comment: The problem was caused due to SSL certificate error and this works perfectly fine. Thanks

Comment: It automatically changes to https at the time of build! What to do?

Comment: I think it's time to update gradle to more newest version.