# libGDX project setup error

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I am trying to create a libGDX project but all i get is errors and when i try to import the project even though i have errors i get more errors and stuff.

Since i cannot post pictures yet i will type the libGDX project setup.

Name: Dodge

Package: com.fam.dodge

Game class: Dodge

Destination: C:\Users\adam-_000\Desktop\Dodge\Gradle Folders

Android SDK: C:\Users\adam-_000\Documents\Android SDK

libGDX Version: Release 1.5.5

Sub projects: Desktop, Android, Ios

Extensions: Freetype, Box2D

Advanced settings: Generate Eclipse project files

And that is basically it. This is the error message(s) im getting:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found.
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found.
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more

Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: There is a problem with gradle right now...
others threads :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576871/cant-build-android-app-with-gradle
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576097/gradle-sync-error-in-android-studio-when-importing-project/29576568#29576568

Comment: Seems kinda lame you can't get the core libgdx libs without gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've the same problem. It's graved in gradle. ( Details here http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-name-matching-localhost-found/ )

But here is a simple solution to the problem. Just change https to http protocol in $(ProjectDir)/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

change line from

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip

to

distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip