# android device monitor not coming up

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I get following error in logs when i click on ADM icon in my android studio. I saw there was already a thread here about this but the solution seems to be for eclipse. However, there is some issue on gradle side today so i changed the https to http in my properties file. I was able to import the project. However, while running it crashes, i want to see the logs and open ADM but it pops up a message with a log file. Following is the end of the  log file

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-04-11 19:04:38.452
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.URIUtil.toURI(URIUtil.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

Could it be because of following gradle certificate issue? 
[Gradle sync error in Android studio when importing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576097/gradle-sync-error-in-android-studio-when-importing-project)

Thanks

Comment: Had this issue just now, closed Android Device Monitor and then this booted up successfuly

Comment: yeah i guess i ended up doing the same !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that no other instance of monitor app is running. It may happen if Android Studio crashes or otherwise.

Kill the `monitor` process and restart.

See also: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72420

Comment: Two monitor.exe processes where running in my case. I killed both and the problem gone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use a Mac and have encountered this problem.

Finally, I found out that **I have opened the Android Device Monitor**, so I closed the previous one and reopened it and it started successfully.
[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49621661/7934652)